# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined at Login.interactive

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

heroku is not working for me.
Can you look at this and help me.

```
$ heroku login -i
heroku: Enter your login credentials
Email: myemail@mail.com
Password: password

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Login.interactive (C:/Program Files/heroku/node_modules/@heroku-cli/command/lib/login.js:183:30)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue then found my pc was not connected to internet . lol . reconnected and it worked.